# Two pointer to the same object

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have two pointers which points to the same object and I need to delete them correctly (delete each object A and the inner object B). But the problem is that the shared object still have memory allocated after delete: A dangling pointer. How can I avoid such a problem without using smart pointer.

```
     class A
        {

        public:
            class B
            {
            private:
                A* m_x;
                A* m_y;
            public:
                B(A* x, A* y);
                ~B();
            };

            B* m_b;
            A(){};
            void Join(A* other);
            ~A();
        };

        void A::Join(A* person)
        {
           this->m_b= new A::B(this, person);
           person->m_b= this->m_b;
        }

        A::~A()
        {
          if (m_b)
          {
            delete m_b;
            m_b= NULL;
          }
        }

        ...

        A aa = new A();
        A cc = new A();
        aa->Join(cc);
        delete aa

        // here I have a problem in deleting the *m_b because it's deleted by the first A 
        delete cc;
```

Comment: Can you show your destructors `~A()` and `~B()`?

Comment: You probably need to implement reference counting yourself, if you don't want to use `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @MaksimSolovjov I added my A destructor

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't understand plz explain more

Comment: @Caramiriel because it might have allocated it in `A::Join`

Comment: @MoezRebai To solve this you would need to reimplement the functionality of [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). That's a pretty tough task, to get it right.

Comment: I think you might want to read about [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). It's excellent for shared resources like this.

Comment: Probably the destructor not doing proper cleanup. You haven't shared the implementation of `B::~B` as far as I can see.

Comment: @skyking actually I didn't put anything in B::~B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without smart pointers, the best you could do is disjoin your `aa` and `cc` at destruction time. But don't do this, use `std::shared_ptr` and forget about similar headaches:

```
// annul pointers to this shared object
B::detach() {
    if (m_x) m_x->m_b = NULL;
    if (m_y) m_y->m_b = NULL;
}

A::~A() {
    // use a temporary pointer, because B::detach will annul the pointers here
    if (m_b) {
        B* tmp = m_b;
        tmp->detach();
        delete tmp;
    }
}
```

Such code is **very** bad. It is unmaintainable, the classes are coupled, and I am not even sure if it is correct.

Comment: Well thanks it solves the issue but can you provide me with an example on how to solve it with std::shared_ptr

Comment: If you use smart pointers instead of regular pointers in every place in your original code and do nothing in destructors, then all three objects will be destroyed when both `aa` and `cc` will go out of scope. This is a slightly different logic, but I think it is preferable, because it is simple.

Comment: At the same time, all three objects will exist as long as at least one of `aa` or `cc` exist; however, this is rarely an issue